# Bootraps 4 Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Good Day,

I`ve been doing a registration form using bootstrap validation. But the problem is I did it correctly but the error style are still the same.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#createaccount").click(function(event) {
    // Fetch form to apply custom Bootstrap validation
    var form = $("#registration")

    if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
    }else{
        $('#registration').on('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:"/validation'); ?>",
                method:"POST",
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                dataType:"json",
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('#createaccount').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                },
                success:function(data)
                {
                if(data.error)
                {
                    //USERNAME
                    if(data.username_error != '')
                    {
                        $('#username_error').html(data.username_error);
                        $("#username").removeClass('is-valid');
                        $("#username").addClass('is-invalid');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#username_error').html('');
                        $("#username").removeClass('is-invalid');
                        $("#username").addClass('is-valid');
                    }

                    //EMAIL
                    if(data.email_error != '')
                    {
                        $('#email_error').html(data.email_error);
                        $("#email").removeClass('is-valid');
                        $("#email").addClass('is-invalid');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#email_error').html('');
                        $("#email").removeClass('is-invalid');
                        $("#email").addClass('is-valid');
                    }

                    //PASSWORD
                    if(data.password_error != '')
                    {
                        $('#password_error').html(data.password_error);
                        $("#password").removeClass('is-valid');
                        $("#password").addClass('is-invalid');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#password_error').html('');
                        $("#password").removeClass('is-invalid');
                        $("#password").addClass('is-valid');
                    }

                    //CONFIRMPASSWORD
                    if(data.confirmPassword_error != '')
                    {
                        $('#confirmPassword_error').html(data.confirmPassword_error);
                        $("#confirmPassword").removeClass('is-valid');
                        $("#confirmPassword").addClass('is-invalid');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#confirmPassword_error').html('');
                        $("#confirmPassword").removeClass('is-invalid');
                        $("#confirmPassword").addClass('is-valid');
                    }

                    //PIN
                    if(data.pin_error != '')
                    {
                        $('#pin_error').html(data.pin_error);
                        $("#pin").removeClass('is-valid');
                        $("#pin").addClass('is-invalid');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#pin_error').html('');
                        $("#pin").removeClass('is-invalid');
                        $("#pin").addClass('is-valid');
                    }

                    //CAPCHA
                    if(data.g_recaptcha_response != '')
                    {
                        $('#g_recaptcha_response').html(data.g_recaptcha_response);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#g_recaptcha_response').html('');
                    }

                    //TOS
                    if(data.invalidCheck_error != '')
                    {
                        $('#invalidCheck_error').html('You must agree before submitting.');
                        $("#invalidCheck").removeClass('is-valid');
                        $("#invalidCheck").addClass('is-invalid');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#invalidCheck_error').html('');
                        $("#invalidCheck").removeClass('is-invalid');
                        $("#invalidCheck").addClass('is-valid');
                    }
                }
                if(data.success)
                {
                    $('#success_message').html(data.success);
                    $('#username_error').html('');
                    $("#username").removeClass('is-invalid');
                    $("#username").removeClass('is-valid');

                    $('#email_error').html('');
                    $("#email").removeClass('is-invalid');
                    $("#email").removeClass('is-valid');

                    $('#password_error').html('');
                    $("#password").removeClass('is-invalid');
                    $("#password").removeClass('is-valid');

                    $('#confirmPassword_error').html('');
                    $("#confirmPassword").removeClass('is-invalid');
                    $("#confirmPassword").removeClass('is-valid');

                    $('#pin_error').html('');
                    $("#pin").removeClass('is-invalid');
                    $("#pin").removeClass('is-valid');

                    $('#invalidCheck_error').html('');
                    $("#invalidCheck").removeClass('is-invalid');
                    $("#invalidCheck").removeClass('is-valid');

                    $('#registration')[0].reset();
                }
                $('#createaccount').attr('disabled', false);
                }
            })
        });
    }
        form.addClass('was-validated');
    });
    </script>
```

```html
<form class="needs-validation" method="post" id="registration">
<span id="success_message"></span>
                                <div class="form-group input-icon-left m-b-10">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control form-control-secondary" placeholder="Username" minlength="4" maxlength="12" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._\s]+" required>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback" id="username_error"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group input-icon-left m-b-10">
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control form-control-secondary" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback" id="email_error"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divider"><span>Security</span></div>
                                <div class="form-group input-icon-left m-b-10">
                                    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  class="form-control form-control-secondary" placeholder="Password" minlength="4" maxlength="12" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._\s]+"  required>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback" id="password_error"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group input-icon-left m-b-10">
                                    <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i>
                                    <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" class="form-control form-control-secondary" placeholder="Repeat Password" required>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback" id="confirmPassword_error"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group input-icon-left m-b-10">
                                    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                                    <input type="password" name="pin" id="pin" class="form-control form-control-secondary" placeholder="Pin" minlength="4" maxlength="12" pattern="[0-9._\s]+"  required>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback" id="pin_error"></div>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                if(get_settings('site_settings','enable_recapcha','')!=0){ ?>
                                <div class="divider"><span>I am not a robot</span></div>                
                                <!-- recaptcha -->
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <div class="form-group"> 
                                        <div class="g-recaptcha-outer">
                                            <!-- get yours: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin -->
                                            <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
                                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo get_settings('site_settings','recaptcha_secretkey',''); ?>"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback" id="g_recaptcha_response"></div>
                                </div>
                                <?php } ?>
    
                                
                                <div class="divider"><span>Terms of Service</span></div>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="0" name="invalidCheck" id="invalidCheck" required>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
                                        <span class="custom-control-description">Accept to <a href="<?php echo base_url('term-of-use') ?>" target="_new">terms of use</a></span>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback" id="invalidCheck_error"></div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-t-10 btn-block" value="Create Account" name="createaccount" id="createaccount"/>
</form>
```

Please check the result below, as you can see I was able the display the error using ajax but the input text still on a success mode. Hope anyone can help me with this I`m not good with ajax and jQuery. If you hate this just ignore my post instead giving my a negative feedback. Thanks
[image]

Comment: before each if, do `$("#username").removeClass('is-valid is-invalid');` to clear classes, tip: you should name the errors returned from the api the same as the field name i.e {errors: {'username': 'foo bar'}}, then you can loop over errors and do the selector like `[name="username"]`, then your not repeating a bunch of lines to set and unset errors.

Comment: hmm sorry, bro the only thing I was able to implement is the $("#username").removeClass('is-valid is-invalid'); others don`t know how to do it since I am pure php and I am using CI framework

Comment: can you show output of `data` ?